# Using If/Else statement, how could I make code decision based on three options instead of the usual two?

Tags: pine-script

I have a code where the value of sto[0] > sto[1] is shown with IF statement where the stochastic line, if true, would turn green, with ELSE statement giving any value that is not sto[0] > sto[1], red. I want to expand/seperate on it to give me if sto[0] = sto[1] or sto[0] < sto[1] are true with each different color.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Ternary Conditional](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D)

Something like that:

```
stoColor = 
  sto[0] > sto[1] ? color.new(color.red, 0):
  sto[0] = sto[1] ? color.new(color.yellow, 0) : color.new(color.green, 0)
```